# Identical code scattered around

Tags: c++

Can someone think of a clean, elegant way to avoid the repetition in the two functions below (apart from writing helper functions for each of the identical blocks of code, or using macros)?

```
void foo (bool b) {
    const int num = std::rand() % 5;
    // code block A
    if (b) {
        // code block B
    }
    else {
        // code block C
    }
    // code block D
    const int number = num + 1;
    // code block E
}

void bar (bool b) {
    const int num = std::rand() % 5;
    // code block A
    // code block C  // code block B not used (bool b used elsewhere though)
    // code block D
    const int number = num < 10 ? num + 1 : 0;
    // code block E
}
```

What is the best way in general to treat something like this?

Idea:  Deal with the different parts only.  Something like

```
enum {Foo, Bar};

template <int N>
struct FooBar {
    void operator()(bool b) {
        const int num = std::rand() % 5;  // Some random number
        // code block A
        if (b) {
            // code block B
        }
        else {
            // code block C
        }
        // code block D
        const int number = get_number(num);
        // code block E
    }
  private:  
    int number(int) const;
};

template<> int FooBar<Foo>::get_number (int num) const {return num + 1;}
template<> int FooBar<Bar>::get_number (int num) const {return num < 10 ? num + 1 : 0;}
```

Comment: "apart from writing helper functions" - why not? That's exactly how to do it.

Comment: In what way are helper functions not clean and elegant?

Comment: @mike it is like programming without using vowels, a challenge for its own sake.

Comment: @mike.  Why not?  Because there are too many here.  It won't be elegant.

Comment: @prestokeys: I don't know what you mean by "too many". The way to write a block of code once, and call it from more than one place, is to make it a function. If you don't want to do it the right way, then there's no sensible way to do it, elegant or otherwise.

Comment: @mike because here there are 5 blocks of identical code but only 2 parts of different code.  With that ratio, shouldn't we deal with the different parts only?  I've posted an idea in my question showing what I mean.

Comment: I see your problem, I think. Apart from templates you can also fold the two functions into one and use an additional discriminating ordinary parameter, bool or enum, which is used to choose between different code paths to emulate the original different functions. But obviously that can become convoluted pretty quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combine foo and bar into a single function which takes two arguments: `bool b`, `bool q`.  The value of `q` would determine whether this new function behaves like foo or bar.

Answer (score 2):

If you have two identical pieces of code in two separate functions, the *only way* to get rid of the repetition is to put them inside a new function (or, of course, a macro).

It is both clean and elegant. And that's what you should do.

Answer (score 0):

Just tossing an idea that seems to work.  Not sure if it is too radical or not.  Would anyone else do it this way?

```
enum {Foo, Bar};

template <int N>
struct FooBar {
    void operator()(bool b) const {
        const int num = std::rand() % 5;  // Some random number
        // code block A
        check_bool(b);
        // code block D
        const int number = get_number(num);
        // code block E
    }
  private:  
    int get_number(int) const;
    void check_bool (bool b) const;
    void code_block_c() const {
        // code block C
    }
};

template<> void FooBar<Foo>::check_bool (bool b) const {
    if (b) {
        // code block B
    }
    else
        code_block_c();
}

template<> int FooBar<Foo>::get_number (int num) const {return num + 1;}

template<> void FooBar<Bar>::check_bool (bool) const {code_block_c();}

template<> int FooBar<Bar>::get_number (int num) const {return num < 10 ? num + 1 : 0;}

void foo (bool b) {FooBar<Foo>()(b);}
void bar (bool b) {FooBar<Bar>()(b);}

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
        foo(true);  bar(true);
        foo(false);  bar(false);
    }
}
// 5.548 seconds

// The following alternative results in no time difference really:
//FooBar<Foo> foo_;
//FooBar<Bar> bar_;
//void foo (bool b) {foo_(b);}
//void bar (bool b) {bar_(b);}
```

Following the suggestion of using another bool parameter:

```
void foo_bar (bool b, bool q) {
    const int num = std::rand() % 5;
    // code block A
    if (q) {
        if (b) {
            // code block B
        }
        else {
            // code block C
        }
    }
    else
        // code block C
    // code block D
    const int number = q ? num + 1 : (num < 10 ? num + 1 : 0);
    // code block E
}

void foo (bool b) {foo_bar(b, true);}

void bar (bool b) {foo_bar(b, false);}

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
        foo(true);  bar(true);
        foo(false);  bar(false);
    }
}
// 4.724 seconds
```

Their suggested solution performs a bit faster, despite the constant if-checks.